# Basic issue regarding Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am a beginner at working with threads.  I'm looking at a block of Code.  I believe it is supposed to run a Method in individual threads for each part in a parts list.  Here is the Code (a):

```
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
      foreach (string part in partlist)
      {
        DoLotsOfStuff(part);
      }
    );
```

To me, that looks like it will run all of that in a single thread.  I would expect the code to look like this, if it is supposed to run the method in individual threads.  Here is the Code (b);

```
    foreach (string part in partlist)
    {
      Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> DoLotsOfStuff(part));
    }
```

Which block of code runs the method in individual threads?  And/Or what changes should be made to accomplish the task?

Comment: You are correct.  The first block of code will run everything in a single thread.  The second will run each iteration of DoLotsOfStuff() in a separate thread.

Comment: BTW: Parallel.ForEach can be better instead of creating a different Task for each part(if the partList is large.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your understanding of how `StartNew()` works.

As per the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx)... `StartNew()` takes an action which it will create a task for and run the action inside of that task.

This happens asynchronously so your calling code continues it's execution.  However the action that you pass to `StartNew()` executes synchronously so in the first code block your entire loop will run within the same thread.  This could be the desired behavior if all you are trying to achieve is have the loop run asynchronously to your main code.  If you are trying to get performance gains by multithreading the work done inside the loop then the second code block is what you want.

**Edit:** As EZI mentions `Parallel.ForeEach` may be better here...  the code would look like this...

```
    Parallel.ForEach(partlist, DoLotsOfWork);
```

`Parallel.Foreach` is more efficient in that it will batch processing and not create a thread for each item in the list but it will also not run asynchronously where as `StartNew` will.

If you want `Parrallel.Foreach` to run asynchronously you can always do this...

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach(partlist, DoLotsOfWork));
```